# print statement never gets executed in a loop

Tags: python

in the below posted code, the first nested for loops displays the logs or the print statemnt as expected. but the latter nested for loops which has `k` and `l` as indces never displys the logs or the print statement within it.
please let me know why the print statement

```
                    print(str(x) + ",,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,," + str(y))
```

never gets displayed despite the `polygonCoordinatesInEPSG25832` contains values

**python code**:

```
    for feature in featuresArray:
        polygonCoordinatesInEPSG4326.append(WebServices.fetchCoordinateForForFeature(feature))
    for i in range(len(polygonCoordinatesInEPSG4326)):
        for j in range(len(polygonCoordinatesInEPSG4326[i])):
            lon = polygonCoordinatesInEPSG4326[i][j][0]
            lat = polygonCoordinatesInEPSG4326[i][j][1]
            x, y = transform(inputProj, outputProj, lon, lat)
            xy.append([x,y])
            print ("lon:" + str(lon) + "," + "lat:" + str(lat)  + "<=>" + "x:" + str(x) + "," + "y:" , str(y))
            print(str(x) + "," + str(y))
            print("xy[%d]: %s"%(len(xy)-1,str(xy[len(xy)-1])))
            print("\n")
        print("len(xy): %d"%(len(xy)))
        polygonCoordinatesInEPSG25832.append(xy)
        print("len(polygonCoordinatesInEPSG25832[%d]: %d"%(i,len(polygonCoordinatesInEPSG25832[i])))
        xy.clear()

    print("len(polygonCoordinatesInEPSG25832 = %d" %(len(polygonCoordinatesInEPSG25832)))
    for k in range(len(polygonCoordinatesInEPSG25832)):
        for l in range(len(polygonCoordinatesInEPSG25832[k])):
            x = polygonCoordinatesInEPSG25832[k][l][0]
            y = polygonCoordinatesInEPSG25832[k][l][1]
            print(str(x) + ",,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,," + str(y))
```

Comment: Can you print and show `polygonCoordinates...` itself? The fact that it "contains values" doesn't mean that the inner loop works.

Comment: Try printing `x` and `y` individually?

Comment: I am not sure, but you shall once look at this `polygonCoordinatesInEPSG25832[k]`. You may find something from it. I am talking about this line `for l in range(len(polygonCoordinatesInEPSG25832[k]))`

Comment: What result it gives to you `print(polygonCoordinatesInEPSG25832[0])`

Answer (score 0):

`polygonCoordinatesInEPSG25832` contain values but `polygonCoordinatesInEPSG25832[k]` don't.
You append it with `xy` but you didn't unlinked it so when you call `xy.clear()` it become empty. Try deep copy it instead.

Comment: would you please explain more with example

Comment: When you use the list variable, most of the time it just inserts it with a pointer to the list. When you edit the list, that new value changes too. An exception may be some typecasting or the return value from the function. Better try this with simple code first. Or use debug print() all over the place to track when the error occur.

Comment: i think it will be great if you provided some code

Comment: Here we go
`
a = []
b = [0, 1, 2]
a.append(b)
b.clear()
print(a)
`
The result you expected is `[[0, 1, 2]]` but you'll get `[[]]`.

But if you use `b = []` instead of `b.clear()`, that'll solve the problem too since `b` is now new instance and that old instance that stored in `a` is not modified.